# How can I use a data-attribute on a div element to hide a custom dropdown + VueJs

Tags: javascript, html, vuejs2, custom-data-attribute

I have a custom form component with a drop-down menu that I have created as a custom component as well. I cannot seem to hide the drop-down as I cannot use a name attribute on a div element.

Each form is unique to the information required from a user so the on the props I added props: ['inputs'] so that I can show input fields as per form

The form component looks like this currently, but the drop down is still visible to the UI.

The  is injected into the form template but for each time the the  is referenced I want to be able to declare it false to not display. Any idea on how I can achieve this. Thanks in Advance.

```
<vue-form :data-dropdown="false" :inputs="{ 'name': true, 'surname': true, 'email': true, 'city': true, 'province': true, 'country': true }"></vue-form>
```

The html for my custom drop-down:

```
<div class="row">
    <div data-dropdown="data-dropdown" class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 pull-left" style="padding-right: 0px">

        <div class="o-pf-required pull-left">*</div>
        <div class="o-pf-dropdown" @click="showDropMenu"><span class="o-pf-dropmenu__label">{{ titleDescription[0] }}</span> <div class="o-pf-dropdown__arrow pull-right"></div></div>

        <ul class="o-pf-select col-md-11 col-lg-11" v-show="showMenu" :class="">
          <li class="o-pf-select__option" v-for="title in titleDescription">{{ title }}</li>
        </ul>

    </div>
</div>

props: ['data-dropdown']
```

Comment: What if you change `v-show="showMenu"` to `v-show="dataDropdown"` ?

Comment: No, It wont work. It will hide the entire component which is what I don't want. The drop-down component is injected into the form component. What I did was, on the vue instance of the drop-down I set a props array - props: [data-drop-down] which I can then use on the element and set to either true or false on the element but I am unsure of an approach to achieve this.

Comment: It would be better if you could provide a complete minimal and verifiable example in a jsfiddle or something.

Comment: Sure. Will do that. Ill extend my previous example I have worked on.

Comment: Hi @Ikbel. Here is the link to the example on jsbin. [Form component with Dropdown](http://output.jsbin.com/nunonid). So what I am trying here is to only display the dropdown in one form. but how can I use the data attribute to target the dropdown -> :data-dropdown="dropdown" and props: [dropdown] and in the data object I added dropdown: false. This is what I initially tried on the actual project

Comment: Ok, I'm still trying to figure out what you are trying to do. so far, I think that you want to show the dropdown component on both forms but only hide the menu on one of them. Here is an updated jsbin: http://output.jsbin.com/namafokovu

Comment: Well not entirely correct but you have the idea. Inside of the Form component as you have seen in my example. It will be present all the time but Only make the drop-down visible where I want it to be. So in the first form, it should'nt be there at all. And then in the second form I want it to display. Having a look at it now. Thanks @Ikbel